# Unable to answer a video-call in Quickblox Javascript

Tags: cordova, ionic3, quickblox

I'm using Quickblox Javascript 2.11 in my Ionic 3 project. I've made a chat with the video-call options and all works between android and web. I'm getting a problem during the answer when I'm in iOS, the error is:

> "Can't accept the call, there is no information about peer connection
>   by some reason."

(full log here: https://gist.github.com/niccolofanton/9be410e30c8771139ffe14dbf9e05d93)

I've read the docs and from the example I've made this code to join the chat and set up the onCallListener:

```
QB.createSession({ login: '*********', password: '*********' }, (err, result) => {

  if (err) { console.log(err, err) } else {
    QB.chat.connect({ userId: *********, password: "*********" }, (err, roster) => {

      if (err) { console.log('Chat error:', err) } else {
        QB.webrtc.onCallListener = (session, extension) => {

          var mediaParams = {
            audio: true,
            video: true,
            options: {
              muted: true,
              mirror: true
            },
            elemId: 'localVideo'
          };

          session.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function(err, stream) {
            if (err) { console.log('error getting user media:', err) } else {
              session.accept({});
            }
          });

        };

        QB.webrtc.onRemoteStreamListener = (session, userID, remoteStream) => {
          session.attachMediaStream('remoteVideo', remoteStream)
        };
      }
    });   } });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved, the issue was Quickblox Javascript SDK version: I was using 2.11 but it doesn't work in Ionic3 (I don't know why) but I switched to older vesion (2.4) and now I can answer.

Comment: This is the a simple demo https://github.com/niccolofanton/quickblox-ionic3